# Importing XML to DOM tree in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtxml

I'm using Qt 4.7 on Mac OS X, and I have a QString containing a path to an XML file. I would like to import that file into a DOM tree and store the data as a member variable to a class. What is the best way to do this?

I've been looking at the [QtXml](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtxml.html) documentation, but I can't find a clear way to convert from the `QXml*` classes to the `QDom*` classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to bother with the QXml* classes to traverse the DOM.

The QDomDocument class has a setContent() method that can take an open QFile.

[There's a code sample](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtxml/qdomdocument.html#details) in the "Details" section of the QDomDocument documentation.

```
QDomDocument doc("mydocument");
QFile file("mydocument.xml");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    return;
if (!doc.setContent(&file)) {
    file.close();
    return;
}
file.close();

// print out the element names of all elements that are direct children
// of the outermost element.
QDomElement docElem = doc.documentElement();

QDomNode n = docElem.firstChild();
while(!n.isNull()) {
    QDomElement e = n.toElement(); // try to convert the node to an element.
    if(!e.isNull()) {
        cout << qPrintable(e.tagName()) << endl; // the node really is an element.
    }
    n = n.nextSibling();
}
```